# What is this grass with seed heads like wheat?

Tags: identification, grass

In north New Jersey, this grassy plant that looks like wheat is growing in my backyard. The seed part is light cream color and the leaves are thin. I don't have the exact height but they're more than 1 ft and less than 2 ft.

What is this?

[image: close up of the seeds]

[image: the full plant]

Answer (score 4):

My guess is Orchard grass.  A very wanted pasture grass for animals.[image: orchard grass seed head]

Identifying grasses is at the top of the most difficult to do.  Need to see the cross section (thank you) as well as those Y connections on the grass and of courses the seed heads.  What is it you want to do with your yard, your land?